# How to save Image with Javascript and show it?

Tags: javascript, html, image

On Website, I want to show user's profile picture.

I know HTML img tag can show like `<img src="link">`, but I think this way is danger for user's privacy.

So, I change image get routine.

1. Server get request with `access_key` contain user_id.
2. Parse `access_key`, and get image from S3. (I'm using AWS's S3 for save image)
3. Response Image file to client.

I test this routine with `Postman`(is http request test app) and It shows right picture.

but I don't know how to show this response file with HTML, JS.

Under is Received Image file.

[image: 받은 메세지]

In another questions says, trying `atob()`, `btoa()` and show with base64.

```js
var imgSrc = (PICTURE TEXT);
var newImage = document.createElement('img');
newImage.src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+imgSrc; // btoa(imgSrc), atob(imgSrc) hex.. or anything..
```

but it doesn't work with parse error `atob` or `btoa`.

Any advice for me?

Under, is my simple test image.
if success, you can see cute my little cat.

(I save this file with `.jpg` and read it. in text, but in text, `?PNG~ something`)

```
�PNG


IHDR         �?1   sBIT��O�    IDATx��y�\Gu�NUݵ{�{V�h�Z�mY�7�20���Ā�-&/$px�B�Yy/� �c    a1����H��x_$�K���F���v����lkv���|>�鹷z�����)�.]��  �۳�x�.]�t��1��_��]�t�ҥK�.]�ty�эu�ҥ�[�n���t���x4-�.]��<��?�. �y�.]�"�U�Kx�hXM�����1R� �  �_��߾��W�q�����{�k.~����'��e����ۥ�Q�5�>��{�Ｃ�y���P��V�'f� ��!&����h��zT�=0��hͯ���K��Loo�7b9��?w�W ����g棢���F����ab��&&뭴���f>U��!�g�� ]M��+��c֬3�s~�����oj�"�9�~��9g�W^|�oV�}L8� c��W��68�c��_����� ز��q=Q����z�^����O�Bj����~�:���҅vތ�l��g����ܹm�L;�ig�ݵ
P�>f��^{    ��g�nة�Q�#��#�S��~X&B`Hd�'�F�� LJ9y`|��N=����:B ��F�Y.U�і K��l��3������deqxA@D"z±<���tY|�GF�xŗO:m�A1c���}�j����Po_�P��Z��� ���?mc ���
ca��6�z��*����|�ß�T��+@���N� "G�W����{ �Њ��X "2��I)-��$�,,,hLp��z�P*U��1Fkm��U���H굯x�}w�q$.Aw�rT���T��qm�o]{͵��
7��Z� �sn�EDd� �3�|�Bά��L�L��6��R�d�"`�6�hk������� ]��'��QR�}�]��\J�@/}�˶�w��_L`�,�8��B����{-aG,=�c�������j5�CCCʚ,�ߝ��m-�aD�� ]��>G"2��H}��5����я~  -�-��1։u"�K_�RD�D�Z���yD�
dQ����BR�o���G>Ȯt9"�1Uhu�-t� �֝͒��Mg��IC"
Ð����e��8M��R�����鑑��(��g�ݵur�. �Kd����� ]��������[Iz`j����Ά�'�^������s��W_ݑK��Ȉ! �ᨍ��Y�Wzk �R���ђ�!�����$��k^q> ,]��?��o���o���u�ɛN�H���P7
�e8T��nݲ���'"B`82c�k^�/}��aP6d=W#�lի�U"��[����X0Z�L�
�=���:w�B�0,�\z�����2M׭=f���W^y��ի9����d��]9*ӈ��dN�� ] �l|j�    �   �.�e�Ȉ�R��o�U��<,�q�
[��zB�FQ��䞆0UN��V��[q���p\����?��k��b�
�1��%"etVh�xՕ_��=��ݥ��^��ߜ���qRo��Ւ�DFKEƂ%���2��i� ��ß��;]������L'�Y}�7K��{7q�dZ)i��Ш"����驻�nY�j�1&���d�4�.������}�S�6�]�9lf��!"ø����� X�F"G `�8�I����e�ض��o����4��=Q�z֔�O�.Y�w&^~�eeE���:��������I��d�1E��]�{��$��*@�#exd���ow���=�x��Ƞ�2K⁾>.�k�EK @�����hO3����[�
�Xm����o��0������>�6KY0Ҩ�=���8 `��d�&&��PE�&���7�x�O�죤��z]�r��'���?�!rAD��q��a��G�HF�C�����~�Ӄ��r���rk-C��)�Rw�����t��ix��/��!Xe��97�RJ�w_�������Y��#�O�6��t9r����^=:|��G���8��&JRB�4d�L��Xk�F��m�z��*τ�:Wi�$�ݼe���*$',�짙�����W��4Ym�r�a�)��<��:��g?��ݻw/���V��/_)�Tӡ��/��tY, �����g���Kߺ�c���� ��fh83V5��tr˿lʽd�#&����}kOz�?��w�m�PuA�0�[�/�?}ř�@��TW�"ϕV҄a�\.�V!c���jZ-_6r�F�p1����e1@ ��Gν��׿�:�u�V��}��7�x���\�'�x.�n���lGE͸��X�?�|���%ʰ����=>X��2�����z�U�� ,�e�:�Z�D�ւ��!c�!��;v��~(IM������U����W��/>��W]-|�áj~@K ��84007����];s�o�&j9�Q�R��>��?{�����?���N��Z3��TY�\2��H�H��,t�c��5fzz�ɏ��t9R�?a�����q=Da�1@��E��#"쫆'mX�~eYM�������Ûw}�K��{�iw�|�5�:UȆ��#'�;�„�
� 2ι�\�u��p��Ø�difr��}�������wѓLtW�.G�V���Btj��sDD��Պ��w!�U��J� �{��y��k�}�[�]m���ya�j�d�r�"��Z0@Jkk@)�Y@�:˗/?묳�Q`
<��a�(P�#�;�Y�J)�,  !�(�F��h4��v�&EQ�¼���^z�%���!wYFŒ~���(�_r�+?��&�eD�9��Eo�Mc��c���1�Xk�"��x�p<�h�=������|��r��g��_}�k4�����1�JOO��˥r�T*���{�'���\����6�} e�EF[�8ǝ��c��;��s���g�lr{��Wlx�Y�ǻ^�R��hr�AD���Z*m�5�v�c`v>���m�?N����5��,F˿���B����u6y�C�Gk�fZP�(댮��s�)<�}�:��3?��{7�������W�`����<�@�&�� ������?��c� ˌk�5�*�|t��yW�,h[�'`� �,�5`Ik�����\I��߸供��ӟm~�!�+�%F��ZӌdI-����\�    k�I�\��[w\T�� ���!�r����ٗ���]�FFF6m�|ڦ3FFF�1����o���-��MN��5mP�5FYkc��G��������Ws�%�����
�T�ZdQOm`+�Բnѻq��Κ�x����5k�W�X�2FDƘ믿��/-1��I~��=��.]����$�|`�1�     �����#���G�z  ,"0` �{_{k��:��0,��5�~�����^�lù��� ,���ӱ�����@���5k��s��  �� ]�
 ,  �O9��
��EQ�u�]cc�&c��;���\�-����'L����8=�KV[�1���7��߹  �:;�P%�rO+�,2�q82D4�<�����'�G�//����)���p0�`��c��?��o?�wYכ����g�����?��_\H��dv�Nߩ͜ԭ����VR��Ҷ06)�?����ig����ۓ�l:*�ޱ�qb��xn��z�_ �lC���>�j=�n6�z�5���;Hϑ�����TØVQ��͕��ک���HEJSala�|���7�ݟ^?>��3U����_��U�~�3ŞX!�t9��
�w��T��8�m��8^�ZR+et�����Z��Yhԕ��о�����dJ�Rm��>@Q�
��_~��[��q�6p�g�<�)O�ܮB�ׂ��[���E\�f��l.��d�^��H�
�g�:ʠ�Yh5;6O��f�皒B�Ҥ�ą���߿�=�����Q�Ǻ�O�AG�����3��u7ٚ���uϽ D��1k���s�!�!�I���"�R��Ef n���'n�T*EQp�N�S��%�2͞���3�W~���(���6�1��^p���iZ0& di�0 �h,YD�����i!    N?mӆ
�$q=?�2�Q+�L|��o�X�~qG1�hn!��Y ܺeK��B1��j#���j;X1���:��{i��1�q�K.�ddd$M���86J�I'�ڹ���ʯJ�B�Q��&���}��]�={��/Yu�Ze 822��x���3�,2e���wܱ� )k  �1�Xd�����TQ�.]�n��R�j��R=�,�g�
  D�����uyփ���|7�p��(�ݗ��ҷ��2�ZKPŶmۈ��4���H�\2R�T�4^�|�O�#�G��glzFO��8 � 92��8� ������c���n"���#?w����u>*f[E#ҍX6��_����ʯ]��T��킢�n{p�)�����L%��6�F�g�|..f#y���   � 9 ��շ�����3z��S80@���-Z��E�D�3{��m{��������ֻ�8�d١�t�����Ws��ԣ��v��k�_���7�5�NR���\[������%í��o%�8_H��F2���V���w� {��Gd��8<�JO�e��RiilA$)[�)��x;����la�Lc����8�`��;~����<ޜ�?0�}瞅V�e��ǬYw8l��+�r`�5˙H�i:A�-��z{��Nԣ�p�L;�lecs���xl�ة�V�݉��v���oL���l1�-7�M�>��NG�f'�Dzn��s����W���5��鑸>]~e,�Ϯ_�v��v��S���}8H���\)��*�"�c�� �|�sn�2��p�uW|�Pi���Ѱ��� @GL�����8����/{�ĐX�)��<i�vS9�+���mYǏ2ۊU}!�᧷z<Į����`<��u�п��F����o�n�2J+��d�嗿��Zk��߹��?��w��{����~��W��r ��/���Y|+�QM�`����o�}``����#���r��Y���-2����L��K���A�GDJQ��s��A����Eu���a��'��wf���䧣+VL�O���s�4�`k�=���������o����R���� �b�4-3��  �����jX������0��۩��   O��y^�U���������V��MZ�qN=s�E�9A�(
�ˢsxB<(����J'�
```

I'm not sure upper text is completely right because I copy that text many times, but some editor don't show that text, just 1 line(PNG~ line). Sorry to this.

Comment: Can you just send S3 image URL after validating `access_key` and put that in img link.

Comment: @αƞjiβ Simple answer is Yes. but after just one access, if user share link, another people can see another user's image `without access_key`.

Second, I want to reduce getting image process. user save image to local and if not change, not request image no more. just show using `?PNG~~` data.