# AWS S3 image show with HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-s3

I ask this question before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313840/how-to-save-image-with-javascript-and-show-it?noredirect=1#comment108467657_61313840), but there was no answer that solve this problem.

I have `AWS S3 bucket` that saved image. Want to do is getting image from S3 and show it with HTML, but the image will not be public.

So, I create a `Node.js` Server. Server can request and get image from s3 bucket.

Under `Node.js` code is sending image.

```js
modules.export = {
  getImage: function(req, res) {
    // check acceses key
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId    : {{ACCESS_KEY_ID}},
      secretAccessKey: {{SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}},
      region         : {{REGION}},
      endpoint       : {{ENDPOINT}}
    });
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
    var s3_params = {
      Bucket: 'bucket.name',
      Key: 'user_access_key'
    }

    s3.getObject(s3_params).createReadStream().on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }).pipe(res);
  }
};
```

with upper code, I can receive some string.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKFIm.png]

In other HTTP-REQUEST application, it shows me just picture not text.

How can I show a picture with this texts?

===

My trying. (upper string is save in variable `imageText`);

1. just create img tag and set src with upper text.
   [image: try 1]
2. make base64, and set src like `image.src="data:image/jpg;base64," + encoding;`
   [image: origin_fail]
   [image: encoding another way]

all of them give me like under picture (default, NOT FOUND picture)
[image: DEFAULT PICTURE]

3. I copy & paste this texts in notepad, save it with `.png`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, but it saids 'cannot open this file. format ~~~'

Any advice for me please?

Using javascript, I want to save this file to img like ~.png, ~.jpg.
or show it directly like `img.src='data:image/jpg;base64,' + encoding_something;`

Thank you for read my question.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find the reason for this? Thanks. in advance

Comment: @kt-workflow Not actually yet. Now I am doing other work first. sorry.